# Convert RTP Stream into H.264 Via FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, stream, h.264, rtp

i have an raw stream of RTP packets captured into a file called mycapture.dump, how can i convert it into H.264 via ffmpeg.

Do i need to save RTP packets in some specific format or need some development work at ffmpeg side

Comment: Ffmpeg can’t read a raw tcp dump.

Comment: @szatmary what needs to be done, in my case to get the things working.

Comment: In the general case the RTP dump does not contain sufficient information for a decode. Usually PPS/SPS of the H.264 stream are transmitted to the client via RTSP (TCP). Sometimes encoders or streaming servers keep PPS/SPS in band. So let's have a look at your RTP dump.